# pdf document being used by another process

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have two PDF files: `Pdf A` and `Pdf B`. `Pdf A` already exists on the computer's `C:` drive and `Pdf B` gets generated through the program which also lands in the `C:` drive.

What I want to do is combine the two so that the `Pdf A`'s pages show first and then `Pdf B`'s pages show after that.

Here is my code that tries to combine the two given a list of PDFs (`Pdf A` is the first element and `Pdf B` is the second element in the `files` list, and the `destinationfile` is `Pdf A`):

```
public static void MergePdfFiles(string destinationfile, List<string> files)
{
    Document document = null;

    try
    {
        List<PdfReader> readers = new List<PdfReader>();
        List<int> pages = new List<int>();

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            readers.Add(new PdfReader(file));
        }

        document = new Document(readers[0].GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destinationfile, FileMode.Create));

        document.Open();

        foreach (PdfReader reader in readers)
        {
            pages.Add(reader.NumberOfPages);
            WritePage(reader, document, writer);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        //being used by another process
        document.Close();
    }
}
```

The issue appears when the document object tries to close.  It says it is being used another process.

What 'other' process is using it?

Comment: In order to find out which process is using PDFA either use ProcessMonitor or UnlockMe

Comment: have u tried writer.close() before document.close

Comment: let me try adding that.  One moment.

Comment: Didn't work, i still have that same problem "Rebuild trailer not found" or whatever

Answer (score 3):

try to change this line:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destinationfile, FileMode.Create));
```

to this line :

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destinationfile, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.ReadWrite));
```

Comment: hmmm...it now gives me an InvalidPdfException "trailer not found".  Any ideas?